# How does Struts2 map URLs to actions?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to understand something that I used a long time ago, but without knowing how it works.

When I click on an hyperlink like this :

```xml
<a href="name_action.action">Link</a>
```

how does Struts2 activate the action mapped into the struts.xml file ?

```xml
<action name="name_action">
    <result type="redirect">web/page.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 maps URLs to Actions with an [ActionMapper](https://struts.apache.org/docs/actionmapper.html).

> The ActionMapper interface provides a mapping between HTTP requests and action invocation requests and vice-versa.
>
> When given an HttpServletRequest, the ActionMapper may return null if no action invocation request matches, or it may return an ActionMapping that describes an action invocation for the framework to try.
>
> The ActionMapper is not required to guarantee that the ActionMapping returned be a real action or otherwise ensure a valid request. Accordingly, most ActionMappers do not need to consult the Struts configuration just to determine if a request should be mapped.
>
> Just as requests can be mapped from HTTP to an action invocation, the opposite is true as well. However, because HTTP requests (when shown in HTTP responses) must be in String form, a String is returned rather than an actual request object.

---

> By default, the `DefaultActionMapper` is used:
>
> Default action mapper implementation, using the standard `*.[ext]` (where ext usually "action") pattern. The extension is looked up from the Struts configuration key `struts.action.extension`.

NOTE: you shouldn't land on JSP directly, but dispatching them after being passed through an action.